# How is it possible that Rijndael returns different result from string and byte[]?

Tags: c#, .net, aes, rijndael, rijndaelmanaged

Here is my code, first with string:

```
byte[] concatBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
         concatBytes = Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(concatBytes), keyBytes);
         //Console.WriteLine(Transform.Hexa(concatBytes));
} 

public byte[] Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] key)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            rijndael.KeySize = 128;
            rijndael.BlockSize = 128;
            rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            rijndael.Key = key;
            //rijndael.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

            ICryptoTransform transform = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(rijndael.Key, rijndael.IV);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
```

If i change my method parameter `plainText` to `byte[]` than my results are completely different. What am i missing here? Also, we have different results using `OpenSSL` and `Rijndael AES` encryption. Any suggestions how i could fix this?

Comment: Maybe string encoding is different?

Answer (score 1):

[`StreamWriter(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9.aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) class for the specified stream by using UTF-8 encoding and the default buffer size.

Since you're using a different encoding (UTF-8 rather than ASCII), it's not surprising that you get different results.

Comment: I rewrited my code according to your comment, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Here is what i get:

UTF-8

1. e63568071c476aac79ff3fb8c1b5bce3

2. 6ee2abc6ac0c25f234a02e137210c0c4e64068a86f58c881897eba2647933205

3. 7a2728cb0a70ec713b0d458a07acc2c6d5bfb626a56ad9bc946ab3332e9de5c6594eb3379375c2cf
 
Byte:
1. 595f71c741fe1a0f46cd06fdae38d2ca

2. 595f71c741fe1a0f46cd06fdae38d2ca

3. 595f71c741fe1a0f46cd06fdae38d2ca